# Why is jQuery triggering some form submissions but not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a table of data and I want the user to be able to click a column header and send a non-AJAX request that reloads the page with the data sorted by that column.

I could just make the column title a link, but **I want them to be able to click anywhere in the column header** so I've added hidden forms and I'm trying to use jQuery to submit the form when the clicks the column header.

The problem I'm hitting is that although it **works exactly as expected for the second col header** -- a click submits the hidden form and reloads the page -- but **does not work at all for the first col header** -- the form does not get submitted.

1. What is keeping the first column's form from being submitted?
2. Is there a better way to do this than using a hidden form?

---

HTML:

```
<th class='sortable'> 
  <form action='/procurements' class='sort_form' method='get'> 
    <input name='sort' type='hidden' value='title' /> 
  </form> 
  Title
  <img class='sort_indicator' src='/images/sort_unsorted.jpg' /> 
</th> 
<th class='sortable'> 
  <form action='/procurements' class='sort_form' method='get'> 
    <input name='sort' type='hidden' value='nature' /> 
  </form> 
  Procurement type
  <img class='sort_indicator' src='/images/sort_unsorted.jpg' /> 
</th>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table.tgr_datagrid th.sortable').click(
    function() {
      $(this).children( 'form' ).submit();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I agree with Marcus that a form is probably not necessary.  Even more, you could probably accomplish the same thing (of whatever you're doing) with an AJAX request and not need to clear/refresh the whole page.

Comment: Re: downvote. Please explain when downvoting. A downvote with no explanation is unhelpful.

Comment: @vol7ron: There are specific reasons why I'm not using an AJAX request here. AJAX is great for a lot of things, but it isn't the best solution in every situation. About the necessity/non-necessity of the form, agreed. So what would be your alternative suggestion?

Comment: @Ethan: If choosing non-AJAX, the only situation I think I could imagine is simplicity of security (passing/setting cookies), really everything can be done through AJAX.  Since you're doing a whole page refresh, do similar to Marcus's solution, but don't use table, use `div` or `span` around whatever you're clicking.  Basically, reduce the unnecessary HTML markup and only use what's necessary.  Otherwise, you should be looking at using a datagrid, which makes it easy to produce sortable tables.

Comment: @vol7ron Your suggestions are uninformed as to OP's situation. What we do know is that OP has a "table of data". A table is not merely being used to style the buttons, it is a **table of data**. However as you suggest table sorting is possible purely in jQuery without the need for a page refresh, but that is not the question. If you have down voted the question I would suggest that you reverse your vote, since your reasons against it are invalid.

Comment: @Marcus: why would I downvote?  You are correct, that's how the question starts out.  The better question is why was non-AJAX specified?  Especially since there are plugins that do this and all that's being accomplished is increased network saturation.

Comment: Actually, AJAX isn't even necessary, this should be done in pure JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: @vol7ron Then we are agreed. :)

Comment: Yes, your table was not complete with data (or other table rows), which was throwing me off... and Ethan's example didn't include any example data, which also is no bueno.  I still reiterate that if the data's the same then the sorting should be accomplished in JavaScript.  If the page needs to be reloaded, it should only be for the purpose of serving cases where JS is turned off (something I don't support any longer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just doing a `GET` request then don't bother using a `form` at all:

```
$('table.tgr_datagrid th.sortable').click(function() {
    window.location = '/procurements?sort=' + $(this).text();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/NL3km/

So in the context of your code you could have this, (note the custom `data-sort-name` attributes):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class='sortable' data-sort-name="title">
            Title
            <img class='sort_indicator' src='/images/sort_unsorted.jpg' /> 
        </th> 
        <th class='sortable' data-sort-name="nature"> 
            Procurement type
            <img class='sort_indicator' src='/images/sort_unsorted.jpg' /> 
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('th.sortable').click(function() {
    window.location = '/procurements?sort=' + $(this).attr('data-sort-name');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Is that pretty reliable across different browsers?

Comment: I have added a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/NL3km/) which shows how you can do this in the way I have suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. Yeah, `alert()` was already working with all of the col headers no problem. It was just form submission that was failing on the first column.

Comment: @Ethan My answer (and example) is arguing against the use of forms. I made a mistake in my answer however, I have changed the last block of code to use `window.location` and not `alert` in the click binding. This will give you the refresh effect.

Comment: BTW if you're advising not to use a `form`, you might as well also say, don't use a `table` where simple `div`/`span`'s will work fine.

Comment: @vol7ron OP is sorting tabular data I think, so a table is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Marcus: it's not valid if he's doing a full page refresh.  It might make sense if he was doing an AJAX call, but he stated above that he is not.

Comment: @vol7ron I am not sure why the validity of using a `table` element for his data is effected by whether or not he is using an AJAX call to update it?

Comment: @Marcus: based on what's happening, he's not sorting the table in-page.  He's calling a script, which is doing processing and returning a sorted table, which implies there is no initial table.  That means he essentially just has buttons and using a `table` element for formatting the buttons is not only unnecessary, but discouraged.  You're better to use a list or div/spans, as I stated. -- If he weren't reloading the page (where AJAX comes in), it might make sense to have a table, since you want to minimize the JS processing.

Comment: @vol7ron You are mistaken, the question starts with "I have a table of data", OP wants to enable the users to click on the headings in order to refresh the page with a different GET argument specifying the column to sort on. I assume maybe some PHP is doing the ordering ot maybe some other JS, however this is not important; jQuery is being used to dynamically create that ability.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `.each()` around the `.click()`, otherwise you'll only be issuing the click on the last element of the array/object returned (as you've noticed).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('table.tgr_datagrid th.sortable').each(function(){ 
      $(this).click(function() { $(this).children('form').submit(); });
   });
});
```

---

#### Other Thoughts:

- There are many other ways you can do this, the question is why are you doing it the way you are and why do you want to do it that way?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure you understand what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to add separate individual onclick handlers to the th elements.